# Python - get process names,CPU,Mem Usage and Peak Mem Usage in windows

Tags: python, windows, memory, process, cpu

I am wanting to get a list of all the process names, CPU, Mem Usage and Peak Mem Usage. I was hoping I could use ctypes. but I am happy to hear any other options. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can't do any better than [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

Comment: In windows your best bet probably would be performance counters.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil).

For example, to obtain the list of process names:

```
process_names = [proc.name() for proc in psutil.process_iter()]
```

For info about the CPU use [`psutil.cpu_percent`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent) or [`psutil.cpu_times`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_times).
For info about memory usage use [`psutil.virtual_memory`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory).

Note that psutil works with Linux, OS X, Windows, Solaris and FreeBSD and with python 2.4 through 3.3.

Comment: can psutil get network stats **per process**? I googled and read docs for about an hour, haven't found anything

Comment: @chester89 This is unrelated to this question. Please try to search SO for psutil questions about network usage, and after that, if you haven't found a satisfying answer, please go ahead and ask a new question regarding it.In any case you should check [`Process.connections`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.connections).

Comment: How to know the bandwidth it's using via this module

Answer (score 3):

I like using `wmic` on Windows.  You can run it from the command-line, so you can run it from Python.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
proc = Popen('wmic cpu',stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print str(proc.communicate())
```

With `wmic` you can get processes, cpu, and memory info easily. Just use `wmic cpu`, `wmic process`, and `wmic memphysical`.  You can also filter out certain attributes by using `wmic <alias> get <attribute>`. And you can get a list of all commands with `wmic /?`.  Hope that helps!

You can check out the official documentation for WMIC here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that would be great but it will need to be ran as administrator, is there a way to run it as admin before using it in the command-Line?

Answer (score 1):

This Python 3.3 code works for Windows 7 with UAC all the way down.

```
import psutil
import time

def processcheck(seekitem):
    plist = psutil.get_process_list()
    str1=" ".join(str(x) for x in plist)
    if seekitem in str1:
        print ("Requested process is running")   

processcheck("System")
```

Answer (score 0):

"can psutil get network stats per process? I googled and read docs for about an hour, haven't found anything –
chester89"
Don't worry chester89, I've got you covered:

```
import psutil#God-sent module
for i in range(2):#looping twice given https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent '''Warning the first time this method is called with interval = 0.0 or None it will return a meaningless 0.0 value which you are supposed to ignore.'''
    for process0 in psutil.process_iter():#for each process running...
        print(process0.name(),process0.cpu_percent())#...print the name and how much of the overall CPU utilization does this process makes up!
    print('\n'*20)#again, due to the above comment -> "Warning", only the section after this blank space will have useful values!
```