# finding process with maximum CPU usage

Tags: python

To get all the process list im using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI),and code is :

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

But my question is how could i find the process which utilizes maximum CPU resource ?

Comment: visit-http://bsdwiki.reedmedia.net/wiki/Determine_which_process_are_consuming_the_most_CPU.html

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara could you post one using python,im confused on that link

Comment: This might help ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326529/python-get-process-names-cpu-mem-usage-and-peak-mem-usage-in-windows

Comment: try this one-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276281/cpu-usage-per-process-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest rather than using WMI which is windows specific use [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) which is cross platform, then you can use the [process class](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/index.html#process-class) `cpu_percent()` method.

Comment: can cpu utilization obtained for individual process consumptions as well?

Comment: It is per process - you iterate over the processes to get the consumption of each.