# Measure CPU time during Python subprocess.Popen call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running an executable using the `subprocess.Popen` API.

I have also set a timeout since the executable could hang or take too long in the `communicate` call. The problem is that on a heavy loaded server it seems like the run times out often. I think it is because it does not get enough CPU time as I run multiple processes in parallel.

I could increase the timeout, however this is a slippery slope as the machine might become even more loaded (it's used as a Jenkins server).

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=log, stderr=log, ...)
process.communicate(timeout=timeout)
```

Is there a way I can refactor this to instead measure CPU time given to the process and timeout based on that?

I've seen questions suggesting `timeit.default_timer()`. However I am not sure that'll work for me.

Comment: in that case don't use communicate, just wait for the process to complete with a poll loop, and in that loop you can monitor the CPU using `psutil` module and decide according to the CPU taken

Comment: How much load do you realistically expect on the machine? Is your machine is so overloaded that runtime is significantly affected, compared to safety margins of timeouts? Say *all* programs are slower by factor 3 or more due to load, then a single program taking too long appears to be the least of your problems. Your machine is massively undersized in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - get process names,CPU,Mem Usage and Peak Mem Usage in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326529/python-get-process-names-cpu-mem-usage-and-peak-mem-usage-in-windows)